# MATLAB Error using importdata

Tags: matlab

I get an error at the importdata line saying

"Error using importdata (line 137)
Unable to open file."

when I write in 'specimenAl.dat' manually into the function, the program runs fine. How can I make use of the importarray function while defining the argument as an element of an array?

```
material = {('specimenAl.dat'), ('specimenSt.dat')};
A     = importdata(material(1));
Data  = A.data;
Force = Data (:,2);
Displacement = Data (:,1);
Strain = Data (:,3);
```

Comment: I don't have matlab here, but try `importdata(material{1})` to extract the char array from the cell

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. fixed it by using `{}` in

```
A = importdata(material{1});
```

Hope this helps!